# Bind Kendo Grid data with dropdown value

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-dropdown

I have kendo dropdownlist on page which is fetching results from database as below. I also have a grid at the same page at same time which needs kendo dropdownlist value i.e the value from years dropdownlist but I am unable to get it at the same time.This is how I am following. Where I am doing wrong.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 var GridUrl;

    $("#Years").kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "Name",
        dataValueField: "Id",

        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: "../../Service/GetYears"

                }
            }
        }
    });



   $(document).ready(function () {
BindGridData();
  GridUrl = '@Url.Action("Read", "Home")';

});

function BindGridData()
{
            GridDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            type: "aspnetmvc-ajax",
            serverFiltering: true,
            serverPaging: true,
            serverSorting: true,
            pageSize: 10,
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: GridUrl,
                    data: { year: $('#Years').val() }
                }
            },
            schema: {
                data: "Data", total: "Total"
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing line to this

```
year: $('#Years').data("kendoDropDownList").value()
```

should do a trick. You need to get instance of `kendoDropDownListwidget` in order to get its value. You need to do so, because `kendoDropDownListwidget` value is not saved directly into `html` element

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to move the initialisation of the `kendoDropDownList` inside the document ready function.  If you don't you may end up refering to elements that are not loaded (yet).

The second change that should be done is how you get the value from the `kendoDropDownList`.  Usually, you should refer to the widget instead of the DOM element: `$('#Years').data("kendoDropDownList").value()`

Finally, you didn't mention how and when your grid was binded but you may want to refresh the grid data if the user change the dropdown value.  If it's the case, you may want to use `change` event of the dropdown to refresh the grid data.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#Years").kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "Name",
        dataValueField: "Id",
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: "../../Service/GetYears"
                }
            }
        },
        change: function(e) {
            $("#YourGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
        }
    });

    BindGridData();
    GridUrl = '@Url.Action("Read", "Home")';

});

function BindGridData() {
    GridDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        type: "aspnetmvc-ajax",
        serverFiltering: true,
        serverPaging: true,
        serverSorting: true,
        pageSize: 10,
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: GridUrl,
                data: { year: $('#Years').data("kendoDropDownList").value() }
            }
        },
        schema: {
            data: "Data", total: "Total"
        }
    });
}
```